# Preventing the user to click a div when its fading out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a filtering system where the user can filter for answers using more than one category, but the user can't choose more than one option from each category, so upon clicking an option from any category, that category will fade out ... I have the following little problem, if the user clicks on another option from the same category while it's fading out, he will be able to choose two options from the same category ... How can I disable any click on the category when it's fading out ??

Here is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div class="search-list" id="program-list">
   <span class="search-title">Category 1</span>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="program-list">Option 1</span></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="program-list">Option 2</span></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="program-list">Option 3</span></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="program-list">Option 4</span></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="program-list">Option 5</span></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="program-list">Option 6</span></a>
</div> <!-- search-list -->

<div class="search-list" id="trainer-list">
    <span class="search-title">Category 2</span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="trainer-list">Option 1</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="trainer-list">Option 2</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="trainer-list">Option 3</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="trainer-list">Option 4</span></a>
 </div> <!-- search-list -->

 <div class="search-list" id="issue-date">
     <span class="search-title">Category 3</span>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="issue-date">Option  1</span></a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="issue-date">Option 2</span></a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="issue-date">Option 3</span></a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="issue-date">Option 4</span></a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="issue-date">Option 5</span></a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="search-option"><span data="issue-date">Option 6</span></a>
 </div> <!-- search-list -->
```

JQuery:

```
   $('.search-option').click(function(){
       var x = $(this).html();
       $('#filtered-items').append(x);
       $(this).parent('.search-list').fadeTo('slow', 0);

       $('#filtered-items > span').click(function(){
          $('#'+$(this).attr('data')).fadeTo('slow', 100);
          $(this).hide();
           });
        });
```

I tried using the following JQuery code but it didn't work:

```
 $('.search-option').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
       });
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey everyone ... I finally solved it, I had to change the whole structure of the function and use the methods "unbind" and "bind" ... Here is the solution if anyone is interested in it:

```
        $('.search-option').click(work);

    });

 function work(){


                var x = $(this).html();     

                $('#filtered-items').append(x);

                $(this).unbind('click');
                $(this).siblings('a').unbind('click');

                $(this).parent('.search-list').fadeOut('slow');

        $('#filtered-items > span').click(function(){
                $('#'+$(this).attr('data')).fadeIn('slow');
                $('#'+$(this).attr('data')).children('a').bind('click',work );
                $(this).remove();
                });

            };
```

Now the user can't choose more than one option at each category ....

Comment: Niceone! Howevere, it might be slightly overkill, [try my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407709/preventing-the-user-to-click-a-div-when-its-fading-out/5407791#answer-5407791).

Answer (score 0):

You can set an indicator in your function:

```
$('.search-option').click(function(){
   if(indicator) {
     return false
   }
...
}
```

The indicator is something set when the fade starts and clears when it ends. It could be:

- a javascript variable,
- or - you can check the current opacity,
- or - or you can set/clear a class name during the fade.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.search-option').click(function(){
  var x = $(this).html();
  $('#filtered-items').append(x);

  // ADDED LINES  
  $(this).parent('.search-list').find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){return false;});
  });
  // END: ADDED LINES   

  $(this).parent('.search-list').fadeTo('slow', 0);

  $('#filtered-items > span').click(function(){
    $('#'+$(this).attr('data')).fadeTo('slow', 100);
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Alex, I tried your updated answer and it also didn't work, it allowed me to choose more than one option in the category ... Could you please tell me why would the "bind" and "unbind" solution would slightly overkill it ??

Comment: Well I was sure mine worked, and had less code, hence my comment. I dont understand why it hasn't work. It disables the rest of the `<a>` before it fades.

Comment: I really am not sure, I copied your code and pasted it, and still it didn't work ... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the 'search-option' class from all options in a category once it is clicked.

Comment: I got the class removed, and the user still can click more than one option from the same category ...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the click event to null once it has fired:

```
$('.search-option').click(function(){
   $(this).click(null); // set click to do nothing on the clicked element
   var x = $(this).html();
   $('#filtered-items').append(x);
   $(this).parent('.search-list').fadeTo('slow', 0);

   $('#filtered-items > span').click(function(){
      $('#'+$(this).attr('data')).fadeTo('slow', 100);
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

This will only turn off the click action on the specifically clicked element so your other filters will continue to work until each of them has been selected once.  If you want to re-enable the click function after everything has happened you can save the function, disable it, then re-enable at the end as below:

```
$('.search-option').click(function(){
   var fun = $(this).click;
   $(this).click(null); // set click to do nothing on the clicked element

   // OTHER CODE

   $(this).click(fun);
});
```

Comment: The code above will not work because he does not only want to disable the one that was clicked but all the other links in that same category. So he will have to do the above for all links in a category he wants to disable.

Comment: ok... well that can easily be fixed with a `$(this).siblings('a').click(null)`

Comment: When I add the above code or the line of code added by Endophage I get a JQuery error "too much recursion"

Answer (score 0):

Since this all hinges on the user clicking on an element with the class "search-option", just remove that class from the element and its siblings before starting the fade and then restore it with a callback after the fade runs. That way, nobody can click twice:

```
   $('.search-option').click(function() {
        var x = $(this).html();
        $('#filtered-items').append(x);
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('search-option');
        $(this).parent('.search-list').fadeTo('slow', 0, function() {
             $(this).children().addClass('search-option');
        });
   });
```

Comment: I got the class removed, and the user still can click more than one option from the same category ...